# Let $F$ be a field in which we have elements satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2 = −1$. Show that there exist elements satisfying $d^2+e^2 = −1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, sums-of-squares

Let $F$ be a field in which we have elements $a, b$, and $c$ satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2 = −1$. Show that there exist elements $d$ and $e$ of $F$, satisfying $d^2+e^2 = −1$.

Any hint?

This is an excercise from the book: The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know; Golan

Comment: Satz 4 in Albrecht Pfister, *Zur Darstellung von $-1$ als Summe von Quadraten in einem Körper*, http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-40/1/159.full.pdf . I know, not a very useful reference...

Comment: For a self-contained answer to the original problem, I would try specializing Euler's 4-square identity in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/pfister.pdf with $x_1 = a$, $x_2 = b$, $x_3 = c$ and $x_4 = 1$, so that the left hand side becomes $0$. Then, choose $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ in such a way that one (but not all) of the squares on the right hand side becomes $0$, and the equality takes the form $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = 0$. Then, divide this by the one among $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ which is nonzero.

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: Golan -The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know

Comment: @darij Out of curiosity, are either of those different than the way I posted?

Comment: @BillDubuque: My familiarity with Pfister's paper is fleeting, so I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\ d=1\ $ in $\,(a^2+b^2)(\overbrace{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}^{\large =\, 0})\, =\, (\overbrace{a^2+b^2}^{\large x})^2 + (\overbrace{ac-bd}^{\large y})^2 + (\overbrace{ad+bc}^{\large z})^2$

That yields  $\ x^2+y^2+z^2 = 0\ $ which, divided by $\,x^2,\,$ yields the result.

**Remark** $\ $ The latter two summands arise from the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

Comment: thx, and the first hint was enoght XD